# Calculate $\int_\alpha^{T+\alpha-\beta}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}{T}x\right)dx$ using periodicity property.

Tags: integration

To calculate the following integral:
$$\int_\alpha^{T+\alpha-\beta}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}{T}x\right)dx, \ \ \ \alpha\in\mathbb R$$
I apply the periodicity property
$$\int_0^{T-\beta}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}{T}x\right)dx$$
but I do not know if my step is correct.

The presence of $\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}{T}x\right)$ instead of $\cos kx$ gives me some problems. In fact I know that
$$\int_0^{2\pi+c}\cos kx dx=\int_0^{2\pi} \cos kx dx$$
for all $c\in\mathbb R$.

I would appreciate some help with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_\alpha^{T+\alpha-\beta}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}{T}x\right)dx=\frac{1}{\frac{2\pi k}{T}}\sin\left(\frac{2\pi k}{T}x\right)\vert_0^{T-\beta}, \ \ \ \alpha\in\mathbb R$$